# Finding md5 of files recursively in directory in python

Tags: python, hash, md5, hashlib

I want to find the md5sum of files starting with "10" ( could be exe, doc, pdf etc) hence not checking the file extension but only the start two digits. So far I've a script to traverse through the directory and print out  all such files but couldn't get the checksum to be printed for each of them:

```
def print_files(file_directory, file_extensions=['10']):                          
''' Print files in file_directory with extensions in file_extensions, recursively. '''

# Get the absolute path of the file_directory parameter                               
  file_directory = os.path.abspath(file_directory)                                      

# Get a list of files in file_directory                                               
  file_directory_files = os.listdir(file_directory)                                     

# Traverse through all files                                                          
  for filename in file_directory_files:                                                 
    filepath = os.path.join(file_directory, filename)                                 

    # Check if it's a normal file or directory                                        
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):                                                      

        # Check if the file has an extension of typical video files
        for file_extension in file_extensions:                     
            # Not a reqd file, ignore                              
            #if not filepath.endswith(file_extension):             
            if not filename.startswith(file_extension) or len(filename) != 19:
                continue                                                      

            # We have got a '10' file!                  
            print_files.counter += 1                                          


            ## TRYING TO READ AND PRINT MD5 USING HASHLIB/ DOESNT WORK###
            hasher = hashlib.md5()                                            
            with open(filename, 'rb') as afile:                               
               buf = afile.read(65536)                                        
               while len(buf) > 0:                                            
                   hasher.update(buf)                                         
                   buf = afile.read(65536)                                    


            # Print it's name                                                 
            print('{0}'.format(filepath))                                     
            print hasher('{0}.format(filepath)').hexdigest() 
            print '\n'                                       
    elif os.path.isdir(filepath):                            
        # We got a directory, enter into it for further processing
        print_files(filepath)   
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                

 # Directory argument supplied             
  if len(sys.argv) == 2:                                                        
    if os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):                                            
        file_directory = sys.argv[1]                                          
    else:                                                                     
        print('ERROR: "{0}" is not a directory.'.format(sys.argv[1]))         
        exit(1)                                                               
else:                                                                         
    # Set file directory to CWD                
    file_directory = os.getcwd()                                              

print('\n -- Looking for Required Files in "{0}" --   \n'.format(file_directory))

# Set the number of processed files equal to zero                             
print_files.counter = 0                                                       

# Start Processing                                                            
print_files(file_directory)                                                   

# We are done. Exit now.
```

'

Comment: What's not working? Does it throw an exception? Give the wrong result? What?

Comment: What doesn't work - do you get an error? Can you show us what happens?

Comment: It says:

-- Looking for Required Files in "/home/Downloads/10/" --

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list-files.py", line 82, in <module>
    print_files(file_directory)
  File "list-files.py", line 59, in print_files
    print_files(filepath)
  File "list-files.py", line 46, in print_files
    with open(filename, 'rb') as afile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1016328298791839266'

Comment: At the same time if I remove the part below, ## TRYING TO READ AND PRINT MD5 USING HASHLIB/ DOESNT WORK###, the code prints out each file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend that you do not solve this recursively, but instead make use of `os.walk()` to traverse the directory structure. The following code could be the body of your `print_files` function.

```
file_directory = os.path.abspath(file_directory)
paths_to_hash = []

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(file_directory, topdown=False):
    for i, dir in enumerate(dirs):
        for filename in filenames[i]:
            if filenames[:2] == '10':
                paths_to_hash += [os.path.abspath('{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(root, dir, filename)]

for path in paths_to_hash:
    hash = hashlib.md5(open(path, 'rb').read()).digest())
    print 'hash: {0} for path: {1}'.format(hash, path)
```

Comment: So I am planning to extend this approach to such that, pass an text file containing md5 and return only those filename whose md5 are present in the text file. Any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The line printing the hasher should be:

```
print('{0}'.format(hasher.hexdigest()))
```

Comment: The line: "with open(filename, 'rb') as afile:" replace filename by filepath.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed with this line

```
print hashlib.md5(open('{0}'.format(filepath)).read()).hexdigest()
```

I wasnt reading the file but just passing hashlib.md5. Thanks Matt for the insight.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please leave this comment underneath the answer and vote for it. Thanks.